# Alt text of broken image overflows bounds

Tags: html, css

I have set width and height for image and also tested `overflow:hidden` but the `alt` text for broken image overflows the bounds of image and also the image size is lost. How can I limit the `alt` text inside the image box?

```css
img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #ff0000;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.example.com/broken.jpg" alt="This is a long text which overflows bounds of image">
```

Comment: The problem is the broken image, fix the link and you have 0 problems. You can wrap the image in a container then set width and overflow on the container as a workaround

Comment: It breaks the page design and pushes other elements to wrong places. @Paulie_D

Comment: Solve the root of the issue, fix the broken image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that "blockify's" the image will (float, flex, block, inline-block, table etc etc) causes the `alt` text to wrap.

```css
img{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #ff0000;
overflow:hidden;
float:left
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.example.com/broken.jpg" alt="This is a long text which overflows bounds of image">
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.example.com/broken.jpg" alt="This is a long text which overflows bounds of image">
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.example.com/broken.jpg" alt="This is a long text which overflows bounds of image">
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap image tag with div and alt text won't overflow out of bounds.

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

img{
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <img src="http://www.example.com/broken.jpg" alt="This is a long text which overflows bounds of image">
</div>
```